# Unable to overwrite authorized method in policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I want to respond with a custom message when authorization fails. 
I've overwritten the method in the Policy class but it does not return the custom message.

Policy:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine if user can view post
     * @param  User      $user
     * @param  Post $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user
                ->posts()
                ->where('post_id', $post->id)
                ->exists();
    }

    /**
     * [deny description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    protected function deny()
    {
        return response()->json([
                'message' => 'My custom unauthorized message'
            ], 401);
    }
}
```

Implementing in PostController:

```
...
public function show(Post $post)
{

    $this->authorize('view', $post);
    ...
}
```

The response still returns whats defined in the `HandlesAuthorization` trait, i.e.:

```
protected function deny($message = 'This action is unauthorized.')
{
    throw new AuthorizationException($message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this code inside the AuthorizationException.php

```
/**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            $response = [
                'message' => $this->message,
                'status' => 403,
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 403);
        }
    }
```